# How does cassandra handle update request under the hood?

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to understand the storage mechanism of cassandra under the hood

From reading the official doc it seems like

1. write request write to mutable memtable
2. when memtable gets too large, its written to sstable

so I have the following question

1. is memtable durable?
2. if there is heavy update qps does it mean that there is going to be multiple versions of stale data in both memtable and sstable such that read latency can increase? how does cassandra get the latest data? and how is multiple version of data stored?
3. if there is heavy update qps does this mean there is alot of tombstone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is memtable durable?

There is the memtable which is flushed to disk based on size / a few other settings, but at the point the write is accepted - it is not durable in the memtable.
There is also an entry placed in the commitlog which by default will flush every 10 seconds. (so on RF 3, you would expect a flush every 3.33 seconds). The flushing of the commitlog makes it durable to that specific node. To entirely lose the write before this flush has occurred would require *all* replicas to have failed before any of them had performed a commit log flush. As long as 1 of them flushed, it would be durable.

> if there is heavy update qps does it mean that there is going to be multiple versions of stale data in both memtable and sstable such that read latency can increase?

In terms of the memtable, no there will not be stale data. In terms of the SSTables on disk, yes, there can be multiple versions of a record as it is updated over time which would lead to an increase in read latencies. A good metric to look at is the SSTablesPerRead metric which will give you the histogram of how many SSTables are being accessed per DB Table for the queries you run. The p95 or higher is the main value to look at, these will be the scenarios that will be causing slowness.

> how does cassandra get the latest data? and how is multiple version of data stored?

During the read of the data, it will use the read path (bloom filters, partition summary etc) and read all versions of the row - and discard the parts which are not needed, before returning the records to the calling application. The multiple versions of the row is a facet of it existing in more than 1 sstable.

Part of the role of compaction is to manage this scenario and to bring together the multiple copies, older and newer versions of a record, and writing out new SStables which only retain the newer version. (and the SSTables it compacted together are removed).

> if there is heavy update qps does this mean there is alot of tombstone?

This depends on the type of update, for most normal updates - no, this does not generate tombstones. Updates on list collection types though can and will generate tombstones. If you are issuing deletions, then yes, it will generate tombstones.

If you are going to be running a scenario of heavy updates, then I would recommend considering LeveledCompactionStrategy instead of a default SizeTieredCompactionStrategy - it is likely to provide you better read performance, but at a higher compaction IO cost.

Comment: `There is also an entry placed in the commitlog which by default will flush every 10 seconds. `
Doe this mean that even if I specify consistency of Quorum, data will still be lost because commit log and memtable is not durable if any one of the server failed? Or cassandra have some way to recover the data in case of server crash if the data is only in commit log and memtable of quorum - 1 nodes

Comment: As long as 1 of the nodes has the data, it remains - and repair would bring the nodes with it missing back into sync. It needs all of the replicas to fail before flushing to lose it - not just 1 replica.

Comment: But if the consistency is quorum, how does that one node know that it has authoritative latest data? doesnt that defeat the purpose of quorum? or is the example given using some other level of consistency?

Comment: @user18128991 - that is an entirely different question, but quorum means more than half acknowledge the write / more than half are involved in a read. Regardless of the answer here, relating to storage on a single node - with Quorum, multiple nodes will be consulted by the co-ordinator.